# Swift - Instancing a class - difference between with and without brackets

Tags: swift

I have a class

```
class OrderViewDetail{
    var order : Order

    init(order: Order){
        self.order = order
    }
}
```

now what is the difference between:

```
var order1 = OrderViewDetail.init
```

and

```
var order2 = OrderViewDetail.init(order: order)
```

Comment: In Xcode `Alt+Click` on `order` and `order2` will give you more details about the variable types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a major difference between the two actually,

- the first one creates a variable that holds a function, `init(order:)`
- the second one creates a new instance of `OrderViewDetail`

---

```
var order1 = OrderViewDetail.init // type is (Order) -> OrderViewDetail

var order2 = OrderViewDetail.init(order: someOrderObject) // type is OrderViewDetail
```

To use the first variable to create a new OrderViewDetail

```
let order3 = order1(someOrderObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

> var order1 = OrderViewDetail.init

This sets `order1` to the `init` method. You can later use `let eg = order1(Order())` to create a new `OrderViewDetail` object.

> var order2 = OrderViewDetail.init()

This won't compile, as there is no parameterless `init` in `OrderViewDetail`. If you added this, this would create a new `OrderViewDetail` object and assign it to `order2`

Comment: This is a duplicate answer, don't you think?